# appending elements to bootstrap accordion body in internet explorer using jquery

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I was playing around with twitter bootstrap's accordion plugin, and I've noticed that in IE, if you use jquery's append() to add elements to the accordion's body, the body doesn't expand to incorporate the newly added element, which causes half of the element and everything below it to be cut-off. Is there a fix for this? I've tried adding overflow:auto for the css corresponding to the accordion body, but that just makes the user have to scroll down to see the rest of the body. Is there something that'll cause the accordion body to expand automatically to incorporate the new element without cutting anything off, in IE?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has already been solved : [github commit](https://github.com/philBrown/bootstrap/commit/75b8347a05fbe1196f60c771f14ba859315a78ee)

You can use that version to correct the bug.

If you can't modify the JavaScript, there is one **ugly** bypass.

**This should not be used unless certain of the consequences** : if you throw an error somehow in the shown listener, it works. For example :

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown',function() { someUndefinedFunction(); });
```

As a last reminder : **prefer the [updated version of the plugin](https://github.com/philBrown/bootstrap/commit/75b8347a05fbe1196f60c771f14ba859315a78ee) instead of this fix**.